# Symfony assetic dumps contents in console

Tags: symfony, assetic

When I run

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

The contents of the files are dumped in the console and the files are not generated.

This happens with `--env=prod` and/or `--no-debug`. Being Windows, I cannot get to the top to see if there is even an error. Never had this before, what could it be?

PS: I'm using `"symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*"`

Comment: if you are using cmd , try running it as administrator

Answer (score 1):

I though Java was installed because PHPstorm was working, but I needed to install the JRE.

Comment: Wow, I lost an hour looking for a solution of the exact same problem. Thanks